# use java to write a linux tool

Tags: java, linux, function, utility

I would like to use use java to write a tool to use under linux so that I can call it like I call "ls". What do I need to do? I planed to:

1. write a java with main function take my arguments, do the job. How do I return results? Java main cannot return string.
2. Where is the best place to add my jar to in the system? /user/bin?
3. how can I call it with minimum typing? I don't want to type java jar XXXXXX com.mynamespace.myfunction ...... How can i just call it by using a simple name like "ls"?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You might want to consider using groovy as well.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a bash file `/usr/bin/custom_program` pointing to your jar:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/bash
java -jar /path/to/your/java.jar # add any custom command line switches here
```

Don't forget to mark it as executable with `sudo chmod u+x /usr/bin/custom_program`.

Your output would be given as `System.out.println()` calls in your program -- no need to return `String`  from main.

Then, you can call your java program with `custom_program` with the help of the bash script above.

Answer (score 1):

In addition of a shell script, you might also use [binfmt_misc](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binfmt_misc) tricks.

I prefer the shell script, it is probably more portable (some Linux system might not load, or have available, the kernel module required to support `binfmt_misc`)

As the kernel's [Documentation/java.txt](http://git.kernel.org/cgit/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Documentation/java.txt?id=HEAD) explains:

> 2) You have to compile BINFMT_MISC either as a module or into
>      the kernel (CONFIG_BINFMT_MISC) and set it up properly.
>      If you choose to compile it as a module, you will have
>      to insert it manually with modprobe/insmod, as kmod
>      cannot easily be supported with binfmt_misc. 
>      Read the file 'binfmt_misc.txt' in this directory to know
>      more about the configuration process.
>
> 3) Add the following configuration items to binfmt_misc
>      (you should really have read binfmt_misc.txt now):
>     support for Java applications:

```
 ':Java:M::\xca\xfe\xba\xbe::/usr/local/bin/javawrapper:'
```

> support for executable Jar files:

```
 ':ExecutableJAR:E::jar::/usr/local/bin/jarwrapper:'
```

support for Java Applets:

```
 ':Applet:E::html::/usr/bin/appletviewer:'
```

or the following, if you want to be more selective:

```
 ':Applet:M::<!--applet::/usr/bin/appletviewer:'
```

> Of course you have to fix the path names. The path/file names given in this
>      document match the Debian 2.1 system. (i.e. jdk installed in /usr,
>      custom wrappers from this document in /usr/local)

#### using `gcj`

Another possibility (which I don't recommend) would be to use [gcj](https://gcc.gnu.org/java/) (the old Java compiler inside [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)).

`gcj`  enables you to compile a Java program into a native Linux ELF binary executable. But I don't recommend it because:

- few (and less and less) people inside the GCC community are working on `gcj`
- few people are using `gcj` ; I only met only one occasional developer using it
- so `gcj` is becoming obsolete
- `gcj`  generated code which allocates a lot does not perform very well (because it uses [Boehm garbage collector](http://www.hboehm.info/gc/) which is much slower than the GC in other Java implementations). However on Java code with a low allocation rate it may run quite fast (because of the powerful optimizations of GCC done in GCC language-neutral middle-end).
- the Java language supported by `gcj`  is a subset of some quite old Java standard.

Comment: It is not only a link, it is a name `binfmt_misc` so specific that your'll find documentation easily (even when the original link, to wikipedia, is gone)